# I am trying to retreive specific user information from django to react but I keep getting 404 error Not found

Tags: reactjs, django-views

I keep I keep getting 404 error Not found when trying to retreive specific user information. Below is the  django code for get request.

```
class ClientInformationView(APIView):
    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    information = get_object_or_404(ClientInformation.objects.all(), pk=pk, )

    serializer = ClientInformationSerializer(instance=information)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here the react frontend code

```
const ClientInformationGet = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  // const classes = useStyles();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("access")}`,
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
};

 const fetchData = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/list/InformationView/`, config)
        .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
      })
       .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
      });
  };

return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MDBContainer className="container mt-5 mb-3">
        {data.map((item, index) => (
        <MDBRow
          className="item-container my-4 py-2 border bg-white text-dark d-flex "
          key={index}
        >
          <p>{item.age}</p>
          <p>{item.phone_number}</p>
          <p>{item.country}</p>
          <p>{item.city}</p>
          <p>{item.phone_number}</p>
          <p>{item.phone_number}</p>
        </MDBRow>
      ))}
    </MDBContainer>
  </React.Fragment>
);
};
export default ClientInformationGet;
```

Which is best way to retrive user infortion using class based view?

Comment: `pk=pk` iso `pk=request.data`.

Comment: Hey I edit the quiz, Am getting Not found 404 error, thanks for helping